# prevent dropdown using Chosen select

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) multiple to select values from a list.

I'm trying to implement a custom action when clicking a selected value, and it requires preventing the dropdown from showing up. (It should only be prevented when clicking on `div.search-choice`)

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-choice', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();    // not working
    event.stopPropagation();   // not working 
    action();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/RA8ej/150/

Couldn't find any solution, but I know its possible since clicking the `x` of the tag does exactly what I need (with a different action). How can I stop the dropdown?

Comment: do you want to disable the dropdown at the time of page load?

Comment: No, I only want to prevent it when you click on `.search-choice`. Clicking on anywhere else should work as intended

Comment: It may help 80% http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/149/ ... it you stop the action you have to change framework code ,

Comment: the chosen code executed before jquery custom code so there is some jerk here

Comment: @Balachandran I'm trying to avoid that, but you may post it as an answer. I will accept it if I won't find a better alternative.